# publishiing of vb.net application with setup procces

Tags: vb.net

how can i keep the sqlserver install automatically when i install my project with attached my own database to sqlserver 2008 express after publish my project. what is the code i can write to in the setup project under vb.net to keep this happened thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to install Sql Server Express, just tick the appropriate box in the prerequisites screen as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx).

To attach your db look at this article for various ways of doing it: [Detaching and Attaching Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)

I think the recommended way is to use [CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)